# Is Azure Worker Role for an on-premise solution available through Windows Azure Pack or App Fabric

Tags: azure, process, cloud, azure-worker-roles

I am writing an application that will be deployed both to the cloud and to on-premise data-centres (for those clients who, essentially, don't yet trust the cloud with their data.

If i choose to go MS Azure I can use the new cloud project types with their Web and Worker roles. But how can I get the worker roles running for the on-premise variant?

Do I have to write my own host (say as a windows service)? This is not ideal as it requires additional code and deployment.

Is there an Azure compatible approach, say in the Windows Azure Pack or the App Fabric stuff (is App Fabric still current?) that doesn't require the full setup of the private cloud ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't exist in Azure Pack.

There is no need to try and have a Worker Role on premise. All you need to do is to have a Virtual Machine that you install a Windows Service on.

It's easy to create a Windows Service using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).

Deployment of a Windows Service with Topshelf is actually much easier than deployments for Worker Roles because you just run the .exe you create with the `install` and then with the `start` arguments.

Because of this you actually need less code than for a Worker Role since you don't need a second wrapper project.

Comment: If you are trying to run the same code in the cloud and on-premise then you can still create a Windows Service console application and then deploy it to a Web Role (same as a Worker Role for all intents and purposes) using something like [AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy](https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy), or you can deploy your console application as a web job (which probably is available in AzurePack, and if not then a TopShelf .exe runs as a normal .exe anyway without arguments).

Comment: The nice thing then is you never need to reference ServiceRuntime or use RoleEnvironment or other Azure-specific things - the code is agnostic of where it's deployed :))

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used Windows Azure Pack before it does seem capable of providing this functionality in house, however the requirements and setup procedures are intense and it is certainly geared towards enterprise.

A better option is for you to create a console app that triggers the OnStart() and Run() functions for your WorkerRole based on your OS Task Scheduler.

Not too much work in my opinion and you get to keep your WorkerRoles as is but just add the console app for any on premise solutions.

Comment: You usually use RoleEnvironment in the OnStart and Run method so this wouldn't work.

Comment: You can use the RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable boolean to switch between what you do dependent upon where you are (E.g. Azure or Local)

Comment: Yes. But this requires to install the Azure SDK for an onpremise installation which you usually don't want.

Comment: You just need to reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime for the RoleEnvironment variable, no need for an entire SDK install.

Comment: But ms is banging on about how the on-premises code is at parity with the azure version. Extra deployment ought not be needed if this is the case